# Code chunks in R give "unexpected symbol" error

Tags: r, markdown

For some reason, R markdown literally won't do anything without some vague error.
I'm trying to run the simplest code chunk, but I get an error. I've tried both manually typing the chunk, and inserting it from R's selection

[image]

Comment: that is not valid r code. if you want a plain text chunk, remove the `{r}` tag

Comment: Removing the {r} tag doesn't change anything. I still get the exact same errors

Answer (score 0):

`1.s` is not a valid symbol in `R`,

(1) if you are trying to name a variable, it cannot start with a number

(2) name like `s.1` is valid, but you have to make it an object, i.e either assign a value or a function etc. `s.1=1` will work in the Rmarkdown

(3) if you just want to put some text here, you need to comment them by putting `#` before it, i.e.`#1.s`

Comment: I was trying to create an ordered list. All I know that I need to do is create an ordered list in a chunk. How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to type a text list in Rmarkdown, you don't have to write it in the chuck, here is Rmarkdown cheat sheet https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf, you may find how to format the text.